# Error: cannot find symbol class

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

C:\Users\pc\Desktop\proj.android\myapps\src\main\java\org\cocos2dx\cpp\GameHelper.java
Error:(32, 39) error: cannot find symbol class AppStateManager
Error:(293, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable AppStateManager
Error:(294, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable AppStateManager

Comment: put the code also that generated this error

Answer (score 2):

For some reason that is not documented,

**Google Play Services 8.1.0** does not include `AppStateManager`. `appstate` library is nearly empty. Downgrade to **Google Play Services 7.8.0** and it will compile again. There is not much difference between them, you should be fine with 7.8.0